# Website cannot connect to database after web publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The system cannot find the file specified 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6564850
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6590016
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6592544
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6592983
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +878
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6596173
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6600667
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +522

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +722
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +154
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9() +162
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +262
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +49
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +14308960
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +524
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +88
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +188
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +298
   PDBScaffold.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\PDBLite\Proofs of Concept\PDBScaffold\Controllers\HomeController.cs:33
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +217
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +231
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

I am not sure what this means as the webconfig is present and I verified the connection strings are correct.  I even pointed my dev environment at the DB to validate it is right.  I am using the VS web publish feature.  It looks like all files are installed to the right directory and in IIS the site is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states it is using `named pipes`, named pipes is used when doing IPC (Inter Process Communication), set your SQL SERVER up for TCP/IP and make sure you have a connection string that works with that configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately the other services can connect to the database just fine from the same app pool. This cannot be the issue.

Comment: ???  you haven't shown your web.config connection string... how can you say it's not the problem?  The error says the application cannot connect to your DB...  Probably because you are trying to connect via NAMED PIPES

Comment: Because I used the connection strings from my other projects that have no problem connecting.

Comment: `<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://*/Entities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=database;initial catalog=Dev-******;integrated security=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: Not trying to be difficult I just don't understand how my other services can connect just fine and not the site.

Comment: i see database as the server name and integrated security...  typically integrated for asp.net apps is something that must be explicitly configured.  The identity that asp.net worker process runs. Is that identity properly.

Comment: Yes i stripped out the actual names and just left `entity` and the database is indeed called database.

Comment: are you sure integrated is going to work with the worker process identity?

Comment: according to your connect string, the DB is on a server named 'database' so you should be able to ping 'database'

Comment: Just validated that the other website which talks to the same db server is able to connect just fine.

Comment: are they using integrated?  are they using the same identity to run the asp wp?

Comment: Yes everything is identical which is why it's driving me nuts

Comment: @ZachM. I noticed you marked this correct. Did you figure it out? I have a very similar connect string:

`metadata=res://*/my.my.csdl|res://*/my.my.ssdl|res://*/my.my.msl;  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=Stargate;Initial Catalog=Census;Persist Security Info=False;  user id=***;password=***; multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient`

... and am getting the same error. Like you, I have another app that works fine connecting to same database.

Comment: This was a while ago and I remember this information helping me and meant to update the thread but never had time. I am no longer with that company so I cannot revisit the code base. Best of luck, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the DbContext and change DefaultConnection from name of conection you use.

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
 {
    public UsersContext()
        : base("MyDBContext")
    {
    }
 }
```